# How to delete an event in Google agenda with CURL?

Tags: php, curl, google-calendar-api

I'm using a script that create events with something like that:

```
$data = "<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' " . 
            "xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'>\n" . 
            "<category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' " . 
            "term='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event'></category>\n" . 
            "<title type='text'>event title</title>\n" . 
            "<content type='text'>event description</content>\n" . 
            "<gd:transparency value='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event.opaque'>" . 
            "</gd:transparency>\n" . 
            "<gd:eventStatus value='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event.confirmed'>" . 
            "</gd:eventStatus>\n" . 
            "<gd:where valueString='event address'></gd:where>" . 
            "<gd:when startTime='$date"."T$timestart:00.000+01:00' endTime='$date"."T$timeend:00.000+01:00'></gd:when>\n" . 
            "</entry>\n";

curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full");
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($cs,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml'));
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $httpheader);
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

I can get the event ID but I don't know how to delete it then.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using the V2 API, so according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_protocol#DeletingEvents):

> To delete an event, first you retrieve the event you want to delete,
>   then you send a DELETE request to the event's edit URL.

So, first perform a GET request to grab the event you want, grab the edit link from the XML e.g.

`<link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml'
      href='https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/jo@gmail.com/private-magicCookie/full/entryID'></link>`

Then use CURL to perform a DELETE request to that URL. To find out more about that, see [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) which explains to use the `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` option.